I want to insert processing before the FormAPI Core validation
I would like to interleave the processing before the Core validation of the FormAPI.
As for the processing flow of FormAPI,
buildForm() -> [submit] -> Core Validation-> validateForm() -> submitForm()
The flow of FormAPI processing is as follows
I would like to process the submitted value before the validation by Core.
The reason is that in the 'datelist' type of FormAPI, passing a string type as the value value will result in a 500 error.
The following Issue has been submitted but there is no indication in Drupal 10 that it will be supported.
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3318851
So I would like to do the following in custom_module.module etc.
$value = $form_state->getValue('birthday');
$form_state->setValue('birthday', intval($value));

What should I do?

That issue isn’t moving because it is set to the wrong component (documentation) and because contributors have not done what the maintainer asked.

You can set #element_validate on the form element, and this validation will happen before the default/full form validation.
Example:
$form['birthday'] = [
  ...
  '#element_validate' => ['MODULE_FORMID_element_validate'],
  // Or if you are defining the form in the same class as the
  // element is defined:
  '#element_validate' => ['::elementValidate'],
];

In the validation handler, you can set the value on the form element in the manner you showed:
function MODULE_FORMID_element_validate(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $value = $form_state->getValue('birthday');
  $form_state->setValue('birthday', intval($value));
}


Thank you for your response.
I tried that but it did not work.
The custom validation does not go in before Core.
The order seems to be as follows.
buildForm() -> [submit] -> Core Validation-> "MODULE_FORMID_element_validate() / elementValidate()" -> validateForm() -> submitForm()

I think I may have found the cause.
Perhaps the 'datelist' type has a value generated by DrupalDateTime::createFromArray.
It seems that this is happening because checkArray() is called in it.
Do you know how to work around this?

I'm not sure how you are testing, but #element_validate handlers are called before form validation handlers.
